# In EE 2.6 how do we set different localization/timezone site-wide than the server's timezone?

Tags: dst, localization

Presuming alternating DST is no longer an issue, I'm confused about the new change. It seems there is now only one configuration option but that is just for the server's time zone:

> This setting lets you specify the time zone where your server is located.

And they give a clear warning if you just put whatever you feel like:

> If you do not set this preference so that it correctly reflects the location of your server it may cause problems with your dates and times. If you are not sure where you server is located please ask your hosting provider.

- [ExpressionEngine User Guide: Localization Settings -> Server Time Zone](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/localization_settings.html)

So what if we want the system to go by a different timezone setting, e.g. my server is in GMT, but my members, activities, etc. are primarily in New York (GMT-5)?

What are the config settings for this now? There seems to be a new setting, "`time_reference`":

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Master Time Reference
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Options are "local" or "gmt".  This pref tells the system whether to use
| your server's local time as the master "now" reference, or convert it to
| GMT.  See the "date helper" page of the user guide for information
| regarding date handling.
|
*/
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
```

But how do we set a different default timezone for the site? Are one of the old configs still used for that? Can't seem to get it straight.

Related questions pre 2.6:

[Forcing DST settings for users](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1984/forcing-dst-settings-for-users)

[How are we supposed to manage time and respect localization/DST in EE?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-are-we-supposed-to-manage-time-and-respect-localization-dst-in-ee)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the values of the timezone variables below you can use both [PHP timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) (e.g. `America/New_York`) and [CodeIgniter Timezones](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html) (e.g. `UM5`).

Through some [tests](https://gist.github.com/notacouch/5716514) (using `print_r($this->EE->config->config);`):

`$config['server_timezone']` is for your server's timezone.

`$config['default_site_timezone']` is for your site purposes.

What you choose on CP Home > Administration > Localization Settings sets  `$config['server_timezone']` with a PHP Timezone. `$config['default_site_timezone']` remains empty, if it is not manually set in your config.php or bootstrap then the value of `$config['server_timezone']` will be used instead.

As of this writing (EE 2.6.1) you **must** manually set `$config['default_site_timezone']` to a CodeIgniter Timezone because for date entry fields their `field_dt_#` column in the database can only accept up to 8 characters, meaning the PHP Timezone in `$config['server_timezone']` will not be properly saved and thus changing the value in your date entry fields every time you save it as `Fixed`. You can also save `$config['server_timezone']` as a CI value and be done with it if your site and server timezones are the same, however, the select dropdowns on the Localization Settings page will not reflect your settings.

A new config is added, too:

```
$config['tz_country']
```

But it is not clear what this does asides from help populate the dropdown.

Comment: Did you just make a quick plugin to test that? Ah yeah, I fiddled with `tz_country` briefly before, too, did some more just now to make sure. `tz_country` is the country dropdown, `server_timezone` is the dropdown afterwards. The latter takes precedence over the former, but if not set *then* `tz_country` is used at least in the dropdown selection. Format for former is like `us`, `gb`, etc. format for latter is the php.net link you gave. Alright I gotta test `default_site_timezone` as different from `server_timezone` when I get the chance. Thanks.

Comment: @notacouch, just erase the timezone related config variables of config.php. Then, enable php on a file and print the value of ee()->config->config

Comment: [Okay tested this out](https://gist.github.com/notacouch/5716514). For me `default_site_timezone` remains blank. If you do not set it explicitly using CI timezone references you are bound to get errors. While both PHP/CI tz's are fine for both the above config and `server_timezone`, by default EE saves the latter in PHP format. If `default_site_timezone` is not set it will default to `server_timezone`, however, `field_dt_#` can only store 8 chars. Better to save `server_timezone` in the PHP tz (so in the CP the dropdowns autoselect) and `default_site_timezone` in the CI tz (so no breakage).

Comment: @notacouch, please, edit my answer with your tests and conclusions!

Comment: Edited the answer! =) I'm still curious if there are per member localization settings or this config trumps them, but I don't think that's an issue for me so I'm not going to spend time there.

Comment: EE 2.7 apparently deprecates `server_timezone`, see "Developers" in [their release notes](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-7-0). Haven't gotten around to updating yet, curious what the implications are.

Comment: Have been using EE 2.7+ for over a month now and forgot about this. The above link to release notes pretty much sums it up, `server_timezone` is taken out (it is not in the Localization Settings page either), and `default_site_timezone` is used instead. The settings page still has PHP Timezones as values in the select dropdown for that, don't know if it saves as such b/c the `field_dt_#` columns still only take a max of 8 characters. Saving it in your config/bootstrap as a CI value properly reflects the correct PHP Timezone on the settings page. `honor_entry_dst` is finally totally gone.