# dd-mm-yyyy date format in Control Panel

Tags: date, date-format, datetime

I want to show the date format in european style (dd-mm-yyyy). I changed and configured all settings to European. $config['default_site_timezone'] = Europe/Amsterdam doesn't solve the problem. Can anyone help me with this? I am running on EE 2.6.1.

Comment: I could do with this too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this as a bug report to Ellis Lab and followed it up with this comment.

I think there is a misunderstanding on the meaning of “European” format.

By default the dates are shown as mm/dd/yy - which is a US centric format.
Switching to “European” changes the format to yyyy-mm-dd - this is certainly more european but is actually ISO 8601 format

I think the expectation was for “European” to be simply dd/mm/yy (or dd-mm-yyyy).

The same basic idea as the US format but showing the day before the month.

**UPDATE**

You can set a custom date format for entry listings in the CP by using Zenbu

Comment: Ok, can you post the reaction from Ellislab once they replied?

Comment: I doubt anything will be done. It's not really a bug just a misinterpretation. Technically the date format that is used when you set "European" IS European. It's just not the one you want. I guess you will need to alter the core. This is something I need to do but won't be looking at it for a couple of weeks.

Comment: I've had feedback from Ellis Labs and they agree with me that "European" isn't what that format is. They say they will be looking at the matter and actually discussed it recently anyway and are keeping it on the Bug list. I have suggested they allow the specification of a custom format.

Answer (score 2):

If it's on the front-end then you can use date variable formatting to output it however you want. To output the dd-mm-yy format you'd just use:

```
{current_time format="%d %m %Y"}
```

The full reference can be [found here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html) with some data formatting constants included too.

**EDIT**

For the Control panel go to Admin > Localisation settings and set **Server Timezone** to your country and **Default Time Formatting** to European. In additon to this also make sure you go to your Member > My Account > Localization Settings and set this to European too.

That should see the date formatting change to a European format for your account as well as new accounts.

Comment: The title says "in Control Panel", so I doubt setting the date format in the front-end is the solution he's looking for...

Comment: It is not on the front-end but on the backend, a client logs in the backend and maintains the site.

Comment: @janvl My mistake. I simply missed that part. The time spent on the negative comment could have been more wisely spent on providing a positive solution. It's a Q&A forum so focus on providing the answers.

Comment: Your suggestion to set the localisation settings should work but doesn't appear to make any difference in 2.5.5. Could somebody confirm as to whether this is the case?

I've just tried it and I'm still getting the 'standard' US formatting.

Comment: Same problem with 2.6.1. I've tried all possible settings...

Comment: Interestingly, I've just looked at another of my sites also running 2.5.5 and the dates are in a different format. The settings for that site are all US. The dates are in the mm/dd/yy format. On my site with the European settings the dates are shown as yyyy-mm-dd, which I guess is ISO format but still not the required dd/mm/yy

Comment: It does seem like a touch and go problem. You can try setting the `$config['default_site_timezone']` manually as you mentioned in your question Ibe but you may need to use one of the [CI formatted timezones](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html). There's actually quite a lot [more info here](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10919/in-ee-2-6-how-do-we-set-different-localization-timezone-site-wide-than-the-serve) as it seems to be a common problem.

Comment: More info here too: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-are-we-supposed-to-manage-time-and-respect-localization-dst-in-ee